# Regular Expression: Remove Time-Stamp from File-Name

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I'm reading through a directory looking for specific file names. I'm able to remove the document tag `'.xml'` from every file name for comparison. The problem is that about 10% of them have a six digit time-stamp at the end of the title.

```
file_list = os.listdir(directory_address)

for entry in file_list:        
        re.sub('\.xml$','', entry).upper()


#file name examples

filename_1 = 'normal_filename'

filename_2= 'another_normal_filename_A23'

filename_3 = 'stamped_file_name_085373'
```

My program will not know off the bat which files have a time stamp. Some of the files--lacking a time stamp--will also naturally end with one or two numbers. To my knowledge, only stamped file names will end in this format `_######`.

How can I use **regex** to recognize file names with exactly six digits attached to the end `_######` and remove those digits from the string for comparision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `\d{6}$` pattern to match exactly 6 digits at the end of the filename and remove them with [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> import re
>>> filename = 'stamped_file_name_085373'
>>> filename = re.sub(r"_\d{6}$", "", filename)
>>> filename
'stamped_file_name'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by eugene is perfect. I would like to enhance this regex further so that It will work in case of any number of digits after a file name. Here is the modified regex:

```
filename = re.sub(r'_\d*$', "", filename)
```